# Pandas CSV all data NaN - file issues

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a 'csv' file that is exported by a piece of equipment which I am trying to open with Pandas. All data is marked as NaN.

[image]

The first bunch of rows are being skipped due to irrelevant data being dropped. Row 70 contains the desired column headings.

After investigating I have determined that the csv file does not import correctly, but if I open the file in excel and 'save as' a csv file the data loads, but the default import creates 230 rows with only a single column. Note: adding sep=',' does not help here.

[image]

Finally if I open the excel csv, and copy and paste the first column to a text editor, then save that as a csv, everything works fine. It seems apparent that the original exported file for the equipment is not exporting as purely as I need it.

[image]

What is the best way to manage this?
(have not shared the csv as I'm not sure if it would help my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the encoding... I guess I missed that.

Comment: This is a list of Python standard encodings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings